# sjPlot function for specific terms for zeroinflated (ZINF) regression model

Tags: r, plot, static, data-visualization

i need to plot specific terms (from both conditional and zeroinflated model) from zero inflated negitve binomial regression in plot_model function using https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/plot_model_estimates.html. but i get an error (copied below) when i use term function but when i use rm.terms function it do not remove the variables from plot that i dont need. any help would be much appreciated

```r
library(sjPlot)
library(sjlabelled)
library(sjmisc)
library(ggplot2)

library(MASS)
library(pscl)
library(boot)


zinb <- zeroinfl(ivdays~age+sex+edu,
                 link="logit",
                 dist = "negbin",
                 data=caterpillor)

summary(zinb)

plot_model(zinb)

plot_model(zinb, terms = c("age [b]", "age [c]"))
Error in .axisPars(usr, log = log, nintLog = nint) : 
  non-finite axis extents [GEPretty(inf,nan, n=5)]
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(new_value, na.rm = TRUE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In min(dat$conf.low) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In min(dat$estimate) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(dat$conf.high) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: In max(dat$estimate) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
6: In axis_limits_and_ticks(axis.lim = axis.lim, min.val = min(dat$conf.low),  :
  NaNs produced
```

[image]

here is dummy data

structure(list(id = 1:100, age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L,
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), levels = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(2L,
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), country = structure(c(1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("eng", "scot", "wale"), class = "factor"),
edu = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), levels = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "factor"), lungfunction = c(45L,
23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L,
70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L,
50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L,
23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L,
70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L,
50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L,
23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L,
90L, 50L, 62L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 25L, 45L,
70L, 69L, 90L), ivdays = c(15L, 26L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L,
8L, 9L, 15L, 26L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 15L, 26L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L,
9L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L), no2_quintile = structure(c(1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), levels = c("q1", "q2",
"q3", "q4", "q5"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-100L))

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you only want to show age[b] and age[c]. Try the code below:

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjlabelled)
library(sjmisc)
library(ggplot2)

library(MASS)
library(pscl)
library(boot)


caterpillor=structure(list(id = 1:100,
                           age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                                             3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                                           .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"),
                           sex = structure(c(2L, 
                                             1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 1L, 1L),
                                           .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"),
                           country = structure(c(1L, 
                                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
                                                 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                 2L, 2L, 2L),
                                               .Label = c("eng", "scot", "wale"), class = "factor"), 
                           edu = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                             1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                             2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                                           .Label = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "factor"),
                           lungfunction = c(45L, 
                                            23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 
                                            70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 
                                            50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 
                                            23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 
                                            70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 
                                            50L, 62L, 45L, 23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 45L, 
                                            23L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 
                                            90L, 50L, 62L, 25L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 90L, 50L, 62L, 25L, 45L, 
                                            70L, 69L, 90L),
                           ivdays = c(15L, 26L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
                                      8L, 9L, 15L, 26L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 15L, 26L, 
                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                      0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 
                                      9L, 36L, 34L, 2L, 4L, 5L),
                           no2_quintile = structure(c(1L, 
                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                      1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                      3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                      3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                      4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                      5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L),
                                                    .Label = c("q1", "q2", 
                                                               "q3", "q4", "q5"), class = "factor")),
                      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                          -100L))



zinb <- zeroinfl(ivdays~age+sex+edu,
                 link="logit",
                 dist = "negbin",
                 data=caterpillor)



summary(zinb)
plot_model(zinb, type="est")

# See the names of the coeffs, use this for the specification
print(coef(zinb))

plot_model(zinb, type="est", terms = c("count_ageb", "count_agec", "zero_ageb", "zero_agec"))
```

Comment: @ Joel H. thanks dear